# Whole hours from timestamps?

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

How do I select only entries with whole hours from sqlite DB where dates are given as timestamps?

Here is an extract from the DB:

```
 Temper Timestamp   Converted date (only for debugging)
 24.13  1562493806      07/07/2019-12:03
 24.10  1562493746      07/07/2019-12:02
 24.13  1562493686      07/07/2019-12:01
 24.13  1562493626      07/07/2019-12:00
 24.13  1562493566      07/07/2019-11:59
 24.13  1562493506      07/07/2019-11:58
```

And the desired output from SELECT statement:

```
24.13 - 1562493626 - 07/07/2019-12:00
```

I tried using `timestamp % 60 = 0`, but all of the entries above return `mod = 26`, not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get 26 and not 0 is that the timestamp contains seconds also.
 
Convert your UNIX timestamps to datetime strings (without seconds), and then check that the minutes component is `:00`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch')) LIKE '%:00'
```

I suppose you understand that your expected result is not really a whole hour because it does contain 26 secs. 
Only if you omit the seconds it is considered a *whole* hour.
**Edit**:
Check if this is faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (timestamp - (timestamp % 60)) % 3600 = 0
```

or better:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (timestamp / 60) % 60 = 0
```

Comment: I was going to answer, but your inspiration is really the critical part here, I think.

Comment: I'm taking the easy and obvious way here, but I'm not sure what that *Converted date (only for debugging)* really means.

Comment: Thanks!

The colum with the string date was printed beside the timestamp to make it human readable and easy to debug. 

A-ha! I missed that out and forgot to consider the seconds, which are not rounded to 00.

Your solutions looks does what I need, but for thousands of samples it can tax a lot of time.

Comment: That worked! Just now saw your update. Converting to minutes first does it. I suggested ignoring the remainder in seconds by using `mod result < 60` instead of `mod result = 0`, so we can save one division operation in the iteration.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andy both `timestamp - (timestamp % 60)` and `timestamp / 60` (integer division) serve this purpose, to remove the seconds.

Comment: Seconds (0 to 59) are removed with `timestamp - (timestamp % 60)` or `timestamp / 60`

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the explanation of 26 - it is most likely attributed to UTC leap seconds - which is currently at +26.  Using your original post values, I assumed your timestamp column was in seconds - but since time is typically handled with milliseconds I multiple each value by 1000:

So converting 1562493806000 to a UTC time & date:

```
Sun Jul 07 2019 10:03:26
```

This is true of all your values.  So the source of your timestamps in all likelihood includes leap seconds - or didn't account for them if the intention was an exact hour.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **@forpas** I managed to fix the formula. The main problem here is that I was not considering the seconds in the timestamps.

So I checked the seconds from those dates, and realized that my samples are NEVER ending in `:00`, but always in `:26` or `:27`. So I adapted the formula to consider this tolerance in seconds:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE timestamp % 3600 < 60
```

The result of the selection is:

```
23.38   1558008027   2019/05/16      14:00:27
23.25   1558004427   2019/05/16      13:00:27
23.06   1558000827   2019/05/16      12:00:27
22.88   1557997227   2019/05/16      11:00:27
22.94   1557993626   2019/05/16      10:00:26
23.13   1557990026   2019/05/16      09:00:26
23.19   1557986426   2019/05/16      08:00:26
```

Thanks a lot, **@forpas**!